# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError crash with android 4.4.2 emulator and ART runtime

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat, android-runtime

I am getting a mysterious crash with the 4.4.2 emulator running in ART mode. The app works fine with android 5, and 4.4.2/Dalvik. Any help will be appreciated.

```
04-17 08:25:24.126  16404-16404/com.my.package.name E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.package.name, PID: 16404
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' does not implement interface 'java.lang.Runnable' in call to 'void java.lang.Runnable.run()' (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Comment: are you using reflection somewhere in your app?

Comment: I inherited a project with many 3d party libraries. At least one of them, ActiveAndroid, is using reflections heavily. Actually AA was causing another crash early on during app launch when it was scanning app classes for DB models. I had to switch to explicit model registration.

Comment: actually looking more into it, i don't think that's it. is your app using any ndk libraries/JNI? Also - isn't ART experimental pre-5.0..?

Comment: I don't think there is any JNI code in the app. Although experimental, ART works pretty well with all other apps I tried. I think the crash is indicative of some problem with the app.